not able to verify my smart contract on zkSync Era Testnet using Remix and MetaMask

I am trying to deploy my smart contract on L2 but the "verify contract" button is disabled and even after deploying my smart contract is not visible on sepolia.explorer.zksync.io, any idea how to resolve this?
When I try to verify my contract directly on sepolia.explorer.zksync.io, I am getting this error 

"Verify Contract" button is enabled on my end though. Make sure that you're checking it after connecting your MetaMask by selecting Wallet from the Environment selection dropdown.
